# Unity C# going into methods that aren't called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, debugging, methods

My code is going into methods when I'm not calling them and it is messing up the game but I can't figure out how to stop it. I'm new to Unity and C# so sorry if this is obvious.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
using System;
using System.Text;

public TextMeshProUGUI mainText;
    public TextMeshProUGUI titleText;
    public Button b1;
    public Button b2;
    public Button b3;
    public Button b4;
    public Button b5;
    public TextMeshProUGUI b1Text;
    public TextMeshProUGUI b2Text;
    public TextMeshProUGUI b3Text;
    public TextMeshProUGUI b4Text;
    public TextMeshProUGUI b5Text;
    StringBuilder t = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder tt = new StringBuilder();
//this is for variables
    bool delays;
    bool dead;

List<string> weather = new List<string>{"sunny", "rain", "storm", "lightning storm", "dry lightning"};
    string weatherPro;
    string dayWeather;
    bool badWeather;
    List<string> capRes = new List<string>{"responsible", "not responsible", "very responsible"};
    string captainResponsibility;
    List<string> shipCon = new List<string>{"great", "great", "geat", "great", "shipworms", "bad patch"};
    string shipCondition;
    bool badPatchDiscovered;
    bool shipwormsDiscovered;
List<string> ranBool = new List<string>{"yes", "no"};
List<string> deathTime = new List<string>{"yes", "no", "no", "no", "no"};

void Update()
    {
      mainText.text = t.ToString();
      titleText.text = tt.ToString();
    }

    void end()
    {
      clear();
      addTitle("The End");
      b3Text.text = "Play Again";
      b3.onClick.AddListener(Start);
    }

string random(List<string> L)
    {
      System.Random r = new System.Random( );
      int index = r.Next( L.Count );
      string randomString = L[ index ];
      return randomString;
    }
void allButtonsGone()
   {
     b1.gameObject.SetActive(false);
     b2.gameObject.SetActive(false);
     b3.gameObject.SetActive(false);
     b4.gameObject.SetActive(false);
     b5.gameObject.SetActive(false);
   }

   void allImagesGone()
   {
     shipSketch1.gameObject.SetActive(false);
   }

   void newLine(){add(Environment.NewLine);}
   void add(string words){t.Append(words);}
   void addTitle(string words){clear(); tt.Append(words); b3.gameObject.SetActive(true); b3Text.text = "Go";}
   void clear(){t.Clear();tt.Clear(); allImagesGone(); allButtonsGone();}
   void showImage(Image img){img.gameObject.SetActive(true);}
   void button(Button b, TextMeshProUGUI bt, String words){b.gameObject.SetActive(true); bt.text = words;}

void start()
{
      clear();
      badWeather = false;
      dead = false;
      delays = false;
      badPatchDiscovered = false;
      shipwormsDiscovered = false;
      shipCondition = random(shipCon);
      Debug.Log(shipCondition);
      intro();
}

//other methods

void dayLoop
{
        clear();
        button(b3, b3Text, "Next");
        if(dead == true){return;}
        dayWeather = random(weather);
        //if statements depending on weather
        //if statements depending on ship condition
}

void dayLoop1(){dayLoop(); b3.onClick.AddListener(wifeDay1);}
void dayLoop2(){dayLoop(); b3.onClick.AddListener(wifeDay2);}

void day1()
    {
      clear();
      addTitle("Day 1 - At Sea");
      b3.onClick.AddListener(dayLoop1);
    }

void day2()
    {
      clear();
      addTitle("Day 2 - At Sea");
      b3.onClick.AddListener(dayLoop2);
    }
```

That's some of my code, for some reason when "Day 2 - At Sea" is being displayed, the game is going into dayLoop() [I know this bc of Debug.Log]. When it is going into dayLoop() after day2 it is going into start() [I know this because the debug command you see in the code prints a new ship condition]. Generally it was printing a crazy amount of debug commands that were inside dayLoop() when that method was not being called. It did not do any of the actions within the if statements of that method though. I would have included the entire code but it went over the character count.

Comment: try edit the code you've included to be all of the relavent code, if you're reaching character limits cut the irrelevant code. we need to be able to run it and see your results so try create a *minimal reproducible example*

Comment: I added some more, I think I copied everything needed to get it to run

Comment: As it stands `start` will not be called at all .. in order to be called as a message method it needs to be `Start` .. in general it is quite difficult to parse through your code and understand relationships .. if we can not even be sure that the code you show us is what is causing the issues ...

Comment: @Alex for us to help you would need to get your code sample to the point where it could run, actually try running it in a new empty project perhaps. This is still not enough of a picture for us, for instance, we don't know what `intro()` does because it's not in your sample.